# How to access a dictionary value inside a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to access the value of the following :

```
a = [{'translation_text': 'I love cake.'}]
```

Desired output:

```
"I love cake."
```

I tried the following:

```
a['translation_text']
```

and I get the following error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Has anyone experienced the same issue before? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `a = {'translation_text': 'I love cake.'}` or `a[0]['translation_text']`

Comment: `a` is a **list**, containing a single element - dictionary. You are trying to access it like the it was just a dictionary. If you don't want to change what `a` is, you need to use `a[0]['translation_text']` - the `[0]` to get the first (and only) element of the list, which is your dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary is the first item of the list `a`, i.e., you need to access it by using its index, `0`:

```
>>> a = [{'translation_text': 'I love cake.'}]
>>> a[0]
{'translation_text': 'I love cake.'}
>>> a[0]['translation_text']
'I love cake.'
```

Answer (score 2):

just like that :

```
a[0]['translation_text']
```

a is a list. So before accessing to the key 'translation_text', you have to acess to the first element of the list (your dictionary).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I get the following error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Show us what did you type to get this error

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "a" is a list, containing one element that is a dictionary. You have to access first the dictionary a[0] and then add the key 'translation_text', so what you need is a[0]['translation_text']

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary mostly is using key,value pairs for example 'translation_text' is key and
value is 'I love cake.' And with **get()** we can get the value from the key in a dictionary

```
a = {'translation_text': 'I love cake.'}
print(a.get('translation_text'))
```

**Second Solution:**

```
a[0]['translation_text']
```